# Can't create new user via module "services" for Drupal 7

Tags: php, rest, drupal-7

I installed "Services" module for Drupal 7. Create restful service. When i try create new user, i get this:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BTga.png)
This is request it self: 
[Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLWGJ.png)

Registration form contain 3 field,all field required:

1. User name
2. User email
3. Type of account (Two radio inputs)

It's my first question in StackOverflow, so if i do something wrong or gave not 
enough information, please tell me about it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Your error picture and request picture on the same link. Typically it's better to put the actual code into the question anyway instead of linking to an image.

Comment: To test how it work I use Postman (extension for Chrome browser), so there are no code, I just can't understand how to use restful api of "Services" module for Drupal 7.